# The right way to do equals and hashcode of objects held by AtomicReference

Tags: java, multithreading

`AtomicReference` doesn't work with `Objects.equals()` and `Objects.hash()`.

```
    AtomicReference<String> ref1 = new AtomicReference<>("hi");
    AtomicReference<String> ref2 = new AtomicReference<>("hi");
    System.out.println(Objects.equals(ref1, ref2)); //false
    System.out.println(Objects.equals(ref1.get(), ref2.get())); //true but potentially not thread safe
    System.out.println(Objects.hash(ref1) == Objects.hash(ref2)); //false
    System.out.println(Objects.hash(ref1.get()) == Objects.hash(ref2.get())); //true but potentially not thread safe
```

What's the best way to check if two objects held by `AtomicReference` are equal and calculate the same hash in a way that both works and is thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to take issue with this statement:

> `AtomicReference` doesn't work with `Objects.equals()` and `Objects.hash()`.

In fact, `AtomicReference` (AR) does work in at least two senses:

1. AR conforms to the implied specification.  The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) show that the `equals` and `hashCode` methods are not overridden, and that the methods' semantics are therefore defined by `Object`.  Thus, AR objects have "identity" semantics for `equals`; i.e. two AR objects are "equal" if and only if they are the same object.
2. AR's behavior is consistent with other mutable types defined by the standard class library: arrays, `StringBuilder`, other `Atomic*` types and so on.

I will grant you that AR's behavior may not be helpful to what you are trying to do.  But you would find that `Objects.equals()` and `Objects.hash()` have the same problems with the other mutable types that I mentioned.

---

The correct way to compare the wrapped values of a pair of atomic references is:

```
  Objects.equals(ref1.get(), ref2.get());
```

You state (correctly) that this is not thread-safe, but this is (to my mind) expected for atomic types.  As a general rule, a sequence of two atomic operations is non-atomic.  As a general rule, to perform two operations as an atomic whole, you need to do some form of locking.

So a simple (but flawed) approach is to do this:

```
  synchronized (ar1) {
      synchronized (ar2) {
           result = ar1.get() == ar2.get();
      }
  }
```

The flaw is that there is a risk of deadlock ... if two threads execute the above code simultaneously with the `ar1` and `ar2` interchanged.

A (hypothetical) fix for the flaw is to ensure that the threads lock `ar1` and `ar2` in the same order.  You can (almost always) achieve that by using `ar1.hashCode()` and `ar2.hashCode()` to give you a consistent order; e.g.

```
  int h1 = ar1.hashCode();
  int h2 = ar2.hashCode();
  if (h1 < h2) {
      synchronized (ar1) {
          synchronized (ar2) {
               result = ar1.get() == ar2.get();
      }
  } else if (h1 > h2) {
      synchronized (ar2) {
          synchronized (ar1) {
               result = ar1.get() == ar2.get();
      }
  } else if (ar1 == ar2) {
      result = true;
  } else {
      // h1 == h2, but ar1 != ar2
  }
```

But as you can see, in a tiny percentage of cases, hashCode ordering won't work.

And I don't know if there *is* a solution for that subcase ... using mutex locking.

---

The other approach to this is to point out that it is actually unreasonable to expect that you can do this.  Here's the thing.  Even if you were able to test that two `AtomicReference` objects did refer to the same object, that result is only valid for a specific instant in time.  The instant after the test completes, the result could be invalidated by some thread changing one of the ARs.

The bottom line is that the test is *not useful* in that it doesn't tell you anything that your application can rely on.  So (IMO) there is little point in implementing it, and even less point in worrying about race conditions.

The *practical* alternative is to use external locking on `Lock` or mutex objects that don't have the problem of potential deadlocks.

Comment: I need to do an equals and hashcode check if I use an `AtomicReference` as a field in a class. If I would like to check for equality of an object of this class with another one, I will need to check if the two classes have the `AtomicReference` pointing to the same 'value'. Also you don't need to synchronize on both objects, you can just do `synchronized (ar1) {` and put code that involves both ar1 and ar2 and do away with your deadlock issue :) But thanks for your input.

Comment: Your solution to synchronize on jus one AR won't work.  Unless the threads synchronize *on the same AR*, there is no mutual exclusion.  Since they are comparing two ARs, how do the threads "agree" on the one AR to use as a lock?

Comment: And I don't see how you reconcile your implied requirement that there be no race conditions in the testing with the fact that the result of a (hypothetical) race-free test may be invalid the next instant.   There is a clear contradiction here, IMO

Comment: Dissenting opinion: There is no value to the `synchronized` blocks in the examples above. The `synchronized` code does not do anything with the result of the test.  What good is `result` if some other thread could change `ar1` or `ar2` after the caller exits from the `synchronized` block, but before the caller tests `result`?  The only reason why you'd want to know if the variables are equal is because you want to _do something_ with them if they are (or are not) equal.  Whatever it is that you want to do,... _That_ must also be inside the same `synchronized` block.

Comment: Well actually, if you read and digest my entire answer, it is saying essentially the same thing as your comment!  (Ditto my previous comments!)

Comment: Why is the order of the lock acquisition the same in your *if* and *else if* blocks? Shouldn't they be reversed in one case (depending on if the hashcode is smaller or bigger than the other)?

Comment: You are correct.  Corrected.  Though the *real* point of the example is the final `else` which is why that approach **doesn't** work.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the best way to check if two [variables]...are equal...in a way that both works and is thread safe?

That question doesn't make any sense.  Let's say you have thread A which wants to test the variables, and thread B which could change either one of them at any time without warning.

You want to find out if the variables are equal?  OK, then what?  If your "thread safe" equality test says they're equal, What stops thread B from changing either one of them in between the time when you performed the equality test and the time when you did something with the information.

There's no value in knowing whether two variables are equal at some instant in time:  You want to know if the variables are equal *while the program is in some particular state*, and then you want to do something about it *before the state can change*.

So, yeah, you need to be `synchronized` on a lock object, but it can't only be to protect the equality test.  It has to prevent the program from changing the state that you care about during the entire time that you test the variables and then do something based on the result of the test.

Answer (score 0):

You want to block both references for manipulation during `equals` and thus make `equals` threadsafe.

I think you can't do this just with `AtomicReference` since it is not responsible for external synchronization. You have to do this manually by controlling the accessing threads.